# Consulta de dois valores para uma Coluna

Tags: php, sql-server

É o seguinte, tem uma tabela de nome Preco. Dentro dessa tabela encontrasse o preco de venda e custo do produto porem, não consigo imprimir no echo pq o nome da coluna é uma só e nao especifica quem é venda ou custo.

**EDIT**
Query para buscar preço do produto:

```sql
        SELECT Produto.Nome as Nome_do_Produto, Codigo_Fabricante1, Qtde, ProdutoPreco.Preco, TabelaPreco.Nome as Tabela, TabelaPreco__Ide
            FROM TabelaPreco
            INNER JOIN ProdutoPreco
            ON ProdutoPreco.TabelaPreco__Ide = TabelaPreco.Ide
            INNER JOIN Produto
            ON ProdutoPreco.Produto__Codigo = Produto.Codigo
            INNER JOIN Estoque_Atual
            ON Produto.Codigo = Estoque_Atual.Produto 
            WHERE Filial = 1 AND (Produto.Nome like '%IMPERADOR%') AND Preco > 0 AND Qtde > 0
```

Resultado da Consulta acima:

```sql
Nome_do_Produto Codigo_Fabricante1  Qtde    Preco   Tabela  TabelaPreco__Ide
MAC ESPAG IMPERADOR FORTALEZA 500G  7891152234015   1.00000 2.2900000000    Preco   11627049-F321-42DE-A3ED-4101BADDBC32
MAC ESPAG IMPERADOR FORTALEZA 500G  7891152234015   1.00000 1.7000000000    Custo   1D05193A-5045-4592-AA17-E2C1EA4D9260
MAC PARAFUSO IMPERADOR 500G 7891152334142   41.00000    3.1900000000    Preco   11627049-F321-42DE-A3ED-4101BADDBC32
MAC PARAFUSO IMPERADOR 500G 7891152334142   41.00000    2.1800000000    Custo   1D05193A-5045-4592-AA17-E2C1EA4D9260
```

Preciso imprimir os dois valores separadamente no php porem os valores estao em so uma coluna **(Preco)**.

como defini no php:

```php
echo "EAN: " . $row_usuario['Codigo_Fabricante1'] . "<br>";
echo "Nome: " . $row_usuario['Name1'] . "<br>";
echo "Preco de Custo: R$";  echo number_format((float)$row_usuario['Preco'], 2, ',', '.'). "<br>";
echo "Preco de Venda: R$";  echo number_format((float)$row_usuario['Preco'], 2, ',', '.'). "<br>";
echo "Estoque: ";   echo number_format((float)$row_usuario['Qtde'], 2, ',', '.'). "<br><br>";
```

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi sua descrição. Você quer dizer que seu produto ou tem o preço de custo ou o preço de venda, mas não ambos, no campo preço? Não é um tanto estranho?

Comment: vamos la, o produto tem somente uma coluna para o preco de custo e venda, eu so consigo separa los com TabelaPreco.Nome = 'Custo' na consulta do SQL porem, para o echo so posso chamar a coluna preco pra imprimir o preco de custo ou venda

Comment: so preciso imprimir custo e venda com o "echo"

Comment: Talvez uma auto-junção possa ser útil para recuperar os dois preços.

Comment: poderia me dizer como? tem dois dias eu fazendo pesquisas pra solucionar e nao consigo de jeito algum

Comment: pelo  oq entendi ele so vai juntar as informacoes da tabelas mas o meu problema é que as informacoes que eu preciso estao em uma so coluna

Comment: Quando tiver dúvidas sobre queries é importante deixar na pergunta tanto o modelo das tabelas quanto informações que sejam relevantes para que as demais pessoas possam te ajudar. Também é bem útil se o código for simplificado para focar no problema da pergunta. Neste caso há mais dados do que o necessário na query, não é possível saber à qual tablea as colunas pertencem e ficou muito sutil a informação de que há dois registros de "preço" que ficam na mesma tabela, diferenciando-se pela coluna `Nome`.

Answer (score 0):

Não está muito claro na pergunta, mas pelas queries e descrição é possível perceber que cada produto tem 2 registros de preço na tabela `TabelaPreco`. Quando `TabelaPreco.Nome = 'Custo'` tem-se o custo do mesmo e quando `TabelaPreco.Nome = 'Preco'` tem-se o preço de venda.

Há inúmeras maneiras de se resolver este problema e a maioria delas, para facilitar o uso no PHP, deverá juntar as 2 queries apresentadas numa única query.

Como não foram fornecidas todas as informações necessárias para uma resposta livre de erros, tome o exemplo abaixo como base. O importante é ter 2 registros de `TabelaPreco` para cada produto e isso pode ser feito com um `inner join`, conforme apresentado abaixo.

```sql
SELECT Produto.Nome as Nome_do_Produto, Codigo_Fabricante1, Qtde, TabelaPreco.Preco, TabelaPreco_Custo.Preco AS Custo, TabelaPreco.Nome as Tabela, TabelaPreco__Ide
FROM TabelaPreco
INNER JOIN TabelaPreco AS TabelaPreco_Custo
  ON TabelaPreco_Custo.Ide = TabelaPreco.Ide
  AND TabelaPreco_Custo.Nome = 'Custo'
INNER JOIN ProdutoPreco
  ON ProdutoPreco.TabelaPreco__Ide = TabelaPreco.Ide
INNER JOIN Produto
  ON ProdutoPreco.Produto__Codigo = Produto.Codigo
INNER JOIN Estoque_Atual
  ON Produto.Codigo = Estoque_Atual.Produto 
WHERE
  Filial = 1
  AND (Produto.Nome like '%IMPERADOR%') 
  AND Preco > 0
  AND Qtde > 0 
  AND TabelaPreco.Nome = 'Preco'
```

Note que foi mantida uma das queries (a que pegava o preço) e foi adicionado um `INNER JOIN` com a mesma tabela, para buscar o custo, com o trecho abaixo. Neste caso é importante confirmar como juntar os registros da mesma tabela (basei-me no join feito com a tabela `ProdutoPreco`) e adicionar os identificadores da tabela `TabelaPreco`, para resolver os erros da query.

```sql
INNER JOIN TabelaPreco AS TabelaPreco_Custo
  ON TabelaPreco_Custo.Ide = TabelaPreco.Ide
  AND TabelaPreco_Custo.Nome = 'Custo'
```

Obs: mais uma vez gostaria de destacar que a query acima pode não estar correta pela falta de detalhes da pergunta. É impossível saber, por exemplo, se `Preco` está em `TabelaPreco`, `ProdutoPreco` ou qualquer outra tabela.

Comment: amigo desde ja agradeco a atencao! vou tentar ser o mais claro possivel:

Comment: a tabelapreco me retorna as seguinte variaveis na coluna nome (TabelaPreco.Nome) Preco e Custo. A informacao que eu preciso esta contida na tabela ProdutoPreco.Preco onde é exibido o valor das duas colunas {Preco e Custo da TabelaPreco.Nome) em uma so coluna.
E quando vou fazer o echo no php eu so posso encontra o valor da coluna preco